# PaintCode, How to add a frame around a portion of a vector and have it dynamically resize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, ipad, paintcode

I've imported a vector layer from a psd into paint code v1, I'm trying to create a background image and make it universal.

I can't seem to add a frame around the vector, to complicate matters, I only need a portion, the center, of the layer. (The design is based around a circle, it has lines drawn towards the center of the circle.)

I can’t seem to add a frame to dynamically resize the part I need.

I found this http://www.raywenderlich.com/36341/paintcode-tutorial-dynamic-buttons the part about frame ans groups doesn't help me....
When I add a click frame and drag it around the area I need, it's at the same level as the vector layer. I've also tried adding a group around both, but that doesn't seem to obey the frame size either.

I’ve looked through the tutorials and googled adding a frame, but I can’t seem to achieve what I need.

EDIT
[image]

Comment: Ask their support; they are wonderful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frame is supposed to be at the same level as the vectors you're working with.

All you do then is set the resize rules of your vectors. There is a little rectangle in the frame's parameters interface with straight arrows and springs that you can modify to fit your wishes.
I think I also remember a checkbox setting to resize only what's inside the frame.

Now I haven't used PaintCode for a while, but if this doesn't help you, there probably is a problem with your vector layer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this information helps.

But if you resizing doesn't work as you expected. Look carefully at the transformation box (the one with the springs attached). When you have put a frame around your object. The middle dot in this box should be blue instead of green. if t's green, you may have a problem with the originating point of your objects and then the resizing may not work as you expected.